# Doesn't matter what sort of business they are, all of them count money

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

I want to paraphrase the title phrase with `but`, to get something like:
`Business is anything but counting a money`. With an emphasis on 'counting money'. But that looks for me that the meaning is exactly an opposite of what I want to say.

What would be a right phrase?

Thanks

PS: For clarification, context is business could be any kind, from mining & banking to making a coffee and serving biscuits. They produce different sort of goods/services but have one thing in common which is counting money to stay somehow profitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if *counting money* is the right definition, but I think the word you're looking for is **basically**.

> All businesses are **basically** about **counting money**
>   All businesses are **basically** about **saving money**
>   All businesses are **basically** about **making money**
>   All businesses are **basically** about **profit**

And you're right about the usage of *but*, it makes your sentence means the opposite of what you actually want to convey.

Comment: I agree with @Albert that **counting money** does not sound like the right expression. I would say **making money**.

Comment: @fjack nice one.

Comment: Thanks guys. 'counting money' I mean for example, company would not pay more for supplies when cheaper options (with the same quality) are available. Or would not pay more to employee if another one could do the same job for a lesser payment. Technically reducing operational spending is sort of 'making money', of course. But that more like 'saving' rather than 'making'. Would `All businesses are basically (about) saving money` be appropriate then?

Comment: @user3124812 I see, then 'saving money' might work. But I guess the closer term for that is profit (?) All businesses are basically about profit. I think we need an answer from native (I'm not a native English speaker)